# Display new controller on UITableView search tap

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uitableview

Now I have a `searchBar` for search a keyword. When I pick a menu I want to show `dataViewController`. How to show `dataViewController`? 
sorry for bad english.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Override `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` and launch the dataviewcontroller from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way on selecting the row

```
    -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
    ChatPageVC *u = [[ChatPageVC alloc]init];
    u= [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ChatPageVC"];
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:u animated:YES];

}
```

I used here the navigation controller you can use `presentviewcontroller` as what you have used in your project.

Comment: He asked how to push to another controller, not work with labels, images, and stuff like that ^^

Comment: Almost. You're allocating `u` twice (one is only necessary, you can remove the first line). Also, `u` is not a clear name, even if the code is trivial, always try to use clear naming ;)

Answer (score 0):

In `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`, create an object of your `dataViewController` and present it (or push it). 
For example, in Swift,

```
presentViewController(dataViewController, animated:false)
```

Or Objective-C,

```
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

The code may not be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

By using segues, it makes your life easier. You do not have to implement `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. You just just have to drag the segue from the cell of the tableview to your new UIViewController, give it a name and write the following in `prepareForSegue` which is already implemented by Xcode:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"YourSegueIdentifier"]) {
        //Get table data
        NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NSString *text = [self.dataTable objectAtIndex:[path row]];
        // Set Data to Destination View Controller
        [segue.destinationViewController.textView setText:text];
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

### First solution

Use `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`; and `pushViewController:`.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    DataViewController *vc = [[AnotherClassViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AnotherClassView" bundle:nil];
    //You could also pass [NSBundle mainBundle] instead of nil if you have issues

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];

}
```

### Other Solution

If you are using storyboards and `segue`; then you need to :

Link the two view controllers in storyboard (to create an arrow) and give it an identifier, for example "ToDetails", then in code, use

```
[self.performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ToDetails"];
```

### Last solution

If you're using storyboards, you can drag a segue from your tableview to the next controller.